# Monitor / check ajax update of content using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

One of my scenario I want to capture text which will be updated on website through AJAX.
I want to get text using JavaScript by monitoring any change on web page. Text change may occur at any place on web and position can not be confirmed before hand.

I don't want to handle it in readyState with value 4.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: you can use ajax callback function to capture specific element after it is updated

Comment: Any particular reason you want to avoid the readyState callback?  I believe it's the most dependable way.

If it's to be avoided for some reason, you might have to attach listeners to each element on page for change events, and then capture the before and after values.

Comment: I have to insert my JavaScript JS file in third party web pages. In that case I will be not in position to figure out particular tag that I want to inspect for change.